# Using htaccess to protect files

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

I am using htaccess to protect uploaded files from being available publicly (only logged in users can see the files).

My current htaccess consists of:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*).(pdf|exe|doc|jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ access.php?file=$1.$2 [L]
```

This works, however my folder structure is as following:

```
access.php
--------------files
---------------------file
---------------------photo
```

So, in the same dir as access.php is a subdir called 'files', and in files are 2 subdirs file and photo.

How can I capture a more complete path of the file in the htaccess?
Example: files/file/a.jpg
Now it only returns a.jpg

Comment: Do you only have 1 htaccess file?

Comment: On a side note, you should escape the dot (`^(.*)\.(pdf`), otherwise it will also match `files/files/ajpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a [rewritebase](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) so the result should an absolute URL:

```
RewriteBase /
```